# Singular and Plurals in Academic Research

Tags: grammatical-number, writing, scientific-language, academic-writing

In academic/scientific research, should I use the names of fruits in the singular or plural? For example:

> There was a significant increase in the frequency of sweet potato consumption (+18.8%), eggs (+14.5%), yogurt (+12.8%), skimmed milk (+8.8%) and bread (+8.5%), and in the category of “consumed in the last three months” of **mangoes** (+38.7%), watermelon (+18.9%), carrot (+18.3%), kale (+16.2%), papaya (+14.0%), avocado (+13.3%), potato (+13.1%), **grapes** (+12.8%) and **oranges** (+10.9%).

Are singular and plural both accepted (mango/magoes)?

Comment: *Kale* is a mass noun, so you can't pluralize it. And *grape* and *orange* cannot be treated as mass nouns, so you must pluralize them. For many of the rest, both are acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Some words describing foods can only be used as noncount nouns: you can say "we should eat more bread," but not (in the exact same sense) "we should eat two breads a day." Others can only be used as count nouns: you can say "we should eat two pretzels a day," but not "we should eat more pretzel." Confusingly, many food words can be used either way: you can say either "we should eat more potato" or "we should eat two potatoes a day."

Basically it depends on whether a food is viewed as a homogenous substance or as consisting of discrete units.

As [Cambridge notes](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mango), "mango," like "potato," can be used either way; in your context either "mango" or "mangoes" would work (see the "[ C or U ]" note at the top of the definition). ["Grape"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/grape) and ["orange"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/orange), however, are only count nouns, so you have to use "oranges" and "grapes" in your context.